# How to run Wordpress admin on a different subdomain?

Tags: php, wordpress, https

I have the requirement of running the Wordpress admin over https.
We use a cdn to deliver cached content for the site but the cdn cannot accept secure traffic (only one SSL cert per IP allowed, and we run several sites off it). I cannot control redirects for `httpS://www.mysite.com/.`

I would like to have:

```
http://www.mysite.com/blog/
httpS://secure.mysite.com/blog/wp-admin/
httpS://secure.mysite.com/blog/wp-login.php
```

I have tried rewriting the urls as suggested in the article http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL#Virtual_Hosts.

> Hypothetically, you could use a host with a different name, such as wpadmin.mysite.com

Unfortunately trying this as suggested still sends me to `httpS://www.mysite.com/blog/login.php`.

```
# No matter what it redirects to the wrong subdomain for login.php
http://www.mysite.com/blog/wp-admin/
-> httpS://secure.mysite.com/blog/wp-admin/
-> httpS://www.mysite.com/blog/wp-login.php.
```

Also when directly going to  the css files still link to the wrong url (.)

The simple solution would have been to run the blog off `http://blog.mysite.com/blog/`. Unfortunately this has been tried and was decided against for SEO reasons.

Is there anyway Wordpress can do this?

Comment: If I recall correctly, WP has a db entry that names the domain where the admin panel is expected to be, and it will redirect you to that domain when you login and go to the admin panel.  When running a test instance, it can be a real pain to keep them straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/login-subdomain?)? It is a mod on the [WordPress HTTPS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/) plugin.

Comment: Had time to give this plugin a try today and it (wordpress-https v2.0.4 for wordpress v3.3.1) works exactly as I want! Thanks for looking at an old thread.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure if you have seen this article but it's pretty comprehensive when it comes to Wordpress Admin over SSL. Scroll down to the part about Virtual Hosts, and there is information there about setting up the wp-admin as a subdomain.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL

Comment: Yep - I tried this. I've updated the question to reflect the problem I'm having with login.php.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache to serve over SSL, look into [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Using it you can transparently redirect all requests from `https://secure.mysite.com/blog/` to `http://www.mysite.com/blog/`.

Comment: I am already running mod_proxy and doing exactly this. Unfortunately wordpress is forcing urls to `https://www.mysite.com/`.

Comment: Check into `ProxyPreserveHost` directive. You need to switch it on. After that you need to add `ServerAlias secure.mysite.com` to the WP vhost config.

As a last resort you can hack WP to do what you need. Googling reveals a number of HOWTOs.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-ssl-secure-admin/ is exactly what I was after.

Unfortunately its broken on newer Wordpress versions :(

Answer (score 0):

To enable admin access for http://blog.example.com through https://ssl.example.com/wp-admins/blog/wp-login.php with pure Apache config so you have no dependence on Wordpress plugins and updates you may want to...

...use mod_proxy on an HTTPS apache virtual host to forward traffic, ensure ProxyPreserveHost is Off so that host names in the proxy statements are sent through to the wordpress server. Then mod_substitute is used (make sure to turn it on) to fix the broken links coming back from wordpress.

```
<Location /wp-admins/blog/>

  AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE application/json
  Substitute "s|http://blog.example.com|https://ssl.example.com/wp-admins/blog|i"
  Substitute "s|blog.example.com\\\/|blog.example.com\\/wp-admins\\/blog\\/|i"
  Substitute "s|'/wp-admin|'/wp-admins/blog/wp-admin|i"
  Substitute "s|\"/wp-admin|\"/wp-admins/blog/wp-admin|i"
  Substitute "s|'/wp-includes|'/wp-admins/blog/wp-includes|i"
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /wp-admins/blog/

</Location>

ProxyPass /wp-admins/blog/ http://blog.example.com/
ProxyPassReverse /wp-admins/blog/ http://blog.example.com/
```

For the reverse proxy to work, you need to specify the internal IP of the server hosting blog.example.com. This solution ensures this will work even if the upstream server (10.0.0.4) has several name-based virtual hosts.

```
10.0.0.4 blog.example.com
```

For more details, see:

http://tec.libertar.se/how-to-host-wordpress-admin-on-a-seperate-domain-and-subfolder/