# Wordpress admin through sub domain

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress for multiple sites at the same time through the Wordpress network feature.

I would like to move the front end of one of the sites out of the network but I still need to access Wordpress to manage the site. Let's take an example to make things easier to understand.

**Initial situation:**

mydomain.com points to www/myCMS/
I can access the web site by using mydomain.com and the admin through mydomain.com/wp-admin

**Desired situation**

I have changed mydomain.com and make it point to www/MyNewFrontEnd where there is no wordpress installation. This works fine and I'm happy with the result but I still need to access my wp-admin interface to manage this site.

I created a sub domain test.mydomain.com which points to www/myCMS, I have added the sub domain in the network configuration to allow test.mydomain.com + www.mydomain.com to access the same site. So when I go to test.mydomain.com/wp-admin I see the login / pwd page but whenever I try to log in, wordpress redirects me to www.mydomain.com/wp-admin which doesn't exist anymore.

Is there a way to make sure that the wordpress admin stays on test.mydomain.com ? How could I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you still can access to it through the old url, them change it at settings > general.
if not them you can either change it on the database by modifying HOME and SITEURL at wp_options, or change it at your wp-config.php file, it should be something like define('WP_HOME', .... ) and define('WP_SITEURL', ....).

Comment: Hello Tulio, thanks but I only want to use a sub domain to access the admin, if I change the site url it will affect the whole site.

Comment: My bad, i was under the impression that your problem was that you lost your capability to login after trying the described on your question.

 Wordpress multi-sites configuration probably can provide the functionality you want: https://wordpress.org/support/article/multisite-network-administration/.

There are also some plugins out there that will do it for you, like this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread from SE, but it may contain some information to point you in the right direction.

[How to run Wordpress admin on a different subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367581/how-to-run-wordpress-admin-on-a-different-subdomain)